# Condensing the results of a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that pulls student attendance data over a specified date range. I would like to somehow "flatten" the data to give me a single line per student with a count of the attendance marks per class period. My current results look something like this

```
Student Name    PermID      Date        Per1    Per2    Per3    Per4
Student1        11786       2018-12-04   U       U       U       U  
Student2        603697      2018-12-07           U       U                  
Student2        603697      2018-12-10           U       M                  
Student2        603697      2018-12-11           U               L                  
Student2        603697      2018-12-14   U       U       L
Student3        1733        2018-11-27                           L
Student3        1733        2018-12-03                           L
```

but I would likst the results to look like this:

```
Student Name    PermID      Per1    Per2    Per3    Per4
Student1        11786        1       1       1       1  
Student2        603697       1       4       3       1          
Student3        1733         0       0       0       2
```

I don't care about the date in my result since my SQL code only looks back 30 days. Here is a sample of my query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(STU.LN, ', ', STU.FN) AS [Student Name], 
  STU.ID AS [PermID], 
  CONVERT(date,ATT.DT) AS [Date], 
  ATT.A1 AS Per1, 
  ATT.A2 AS Per2, 
  ATT.A3 AS Per3, 
  ATT.A4 AS Per4, 

FROM STU
   LEFT JOIN ATT 
    ON (STU.SN = ATT.SN AND STU.DEL = 0)

WHERE 
  (
  ATT.A1 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A2 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A3 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A4 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ) AND
  ATT.DT >= GETDATE()-30 AND
  ATT.DT != '2018-10-10' AND
  STU.SP <> 'E'

ORDER BY STU.LN, STU.FN, STU.ID, ATT.DY
```

Can this query be rewritten to aggregate the count of attendance codes per period by student so that my data set is flattened to only 1 row per student?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you try `GROUP BY` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a counter point to Gordon, assuming the "blank" values are empty strings, conditional aggregation should work.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(STU.LN, ', ', STU.FN) AS [Student Name], 
  STU.ID AS [PermID], 
  CONVERT(date,ATT.DT) AS [Date], 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATT.A1 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Per1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATT.A2 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Per2, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATT.A3 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Per3, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATT.A4 <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Per4, 

FROM STU
   LEFT JOIN ATT 
    ON (STU.SN = ATT.SN AND STU.DEL = 0)

WHERE 
  (
  ATT.A1 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A2 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A3 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ATT.A4 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
  ) AND
  ATT.DT >= GETDATE()-30 AND
  ATT.DT != '2018-10-10' AND
  STU.SP <> 'E'
GROUP BY 
  CONCAT(STU.LN, ', ', STU.FN), 
  STU.ID, 
  CONVERT(date,ATT.DT)

ORDER BY STU.LN, STU.FN, STU.ID, ATT.DY
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this just requires aggregation.  Assuming that the "blank" values are `NULL`s:

```
with t as (
      <your query here with no order by>
     )
select student_name, permid,
       count(per1) as per1,
       count(per2) as per2,
       count(per3) as per3,
       count(per4) as per4
from t
group by student_name, permid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `studentname` and `permID`, then a `COUNT` for each `per`.

```
;WITH YourData AS
(
    SELECT 
      CONCAT(STU.LN, ', ', STU.FN) AS [Student Name], 
      STU.ID AS [PermID], 
      CONVERT(date,ATT.DT) AS [Date], 
      ATT.A1 AS Per1, 
      ATT.A2 AS Per2, 
      ATT.A3 AS Per3, 
      ATT.A4 AS Per4, 
    FROM STU
       LEFT JOIN ATT 
        ON (STU.SN = ATT.SN AND STU.DEL = 0)
    WHERE 
      (
          ATT.A1 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
          ATT.A2 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
          ATT.A3 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
          ATT.A4 in ('L', 'M', 'A', 'T', 'U') OR 
      ) AND
      ATT.DT >= GETDATE()-30 AND
      ATT.DT != '2018-10-10' AND
      STU.SP <> 'E'
)
SELECT
    T.[Student Name],
    T.PermID,
    Per1 = COUNT(T.Per1),
    Per2 = COUNT(T.Per2),
    Per3 = COUNT(T.Per3),
    Per4 = COUNT(T.Per4)
FROM
    YourData AS T
GROUP BY
    T.[Student Name],
    T.PermID
```

When you want to "flatten" you should think of `GROUP BY`. All columns that are not grouped by will be lost (the SQL engine can't pick one to show, as you are "flattening" N rows by group) unless they are used in an aggregation operation, like `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, `FIRST_VALUE`, etc.

You can also use expressions on those values before the "flatenning" occurs, like for example:

```
Per3WithUValuesOnly = COUNT(CASE WHEN Per3 = 'U' THEN 1 END)
```